# Oracle - Reducing downtime while moving from one database to another

Tags: database, oracle, backup, migrate

Let's say you have an Oracle database running on production-backup.  You want to move back to production (which has no data at this time).  To export, import, index, and run statistics collection takes 4 hours.  So, if you stop production-backup, you are down 4 hours while you migrate back to production.  Part of the long import time is that there is a bunch of historical data in there not immediately needed for operations.  How would you migrate your data from production-backup to production to minimize downtime so that you aren't down for 4 hours?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The preferred option would be to use [Oracle Data Guard](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14239/concepts.htm).  First, you would instantiate the new production database as a physical standby for the current database.  Then, when you wanted to move to the new database, you'd simply issue a switchover from the primary to the standby.  You may want to follow that up by instantiating a physical standby for the new production database on the backup server.

If you don't have the enterprise edition, you can do essentially the same thing manually.  Assuming the database is in ARCHIVELOG mode, you can run a backup of the current production database while it is up, restore that backup to the production server, and then apply archived logs from the current production database to get the backup close to synchronized.  When you're ready to do the switchover, you'd need to shut down the current production database, copy the last archived logs to the backup, apply the archived logs, and then bring up the backup as the new production database.